# Java IO vs NIO vs Tasks queue

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, nio

I've seen a lot of topics comparing the older Java io model to the newer java nio model, the former being synchronous/blocking and the latter being asynchronous/non-blocking.  Because nio is non-blocking, it is more suitable than java io when a large number of concurrent connections need to be processed concurrently without allocating a large number of threads which does not scale well due to context switching/memory usage.

The problem I have with this argument is that comparisons of IO to NIO always give examples of IO using a thread per connection. Could a developer using java IO simply allocate a finite number of threads (thread pool) for blocking IO operations (ie file reading or database queries) and queue them?  Let's say I'm making an http server from the ground up using java's ServerSocket class.  Let's say I get a request from a client that requires me to make a database query which is a blocking operation due to the JDBC spec.  Could I not simply queue the database query to a ThreadPool and hand the job a callback to run when the pool finishes handling it?  Sure, I'm allocating threads to handle io-bounds requests, but the number of Threads are finite. Since IO operations are typically synchronous (to a degree), it would be pointless to try to allocate a thread per db query, or thread per file read/write.

This way you can get the benefits of Threads and asynchronous programming without the consequence of allocating too many Threads.

The only weakness I can see in this model is if all io-bound operations get stuck (possibly due to programming error) future queued requests will be put on hold until they either get unstuck, or time out.  The main logic is still concurrent, but the IO is not.

So, question: Does NIO solve any problems that just can't be solved with the model I've described above (bar the potential weakness I just mentioned)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can do this with a pool and a finite number of threads and handle your own I/O, but you'd be basically duplicating what NIO is providing for you, but without being able to take advantage of native API's.

One of the problems your system could not handle very well is having thousands of sockets doing slow I/O as would be needed for handling server push, a BitTorrent client or perhaps a very busy content server.

More traditional request/response systems would work fine with your solution, but then again, they would also work fine with a thread per request as usually the first bottleneck encountered will be CPU or Memory consumption.

Comment: I'm supposing then that NIO allows for asynchronous IO without the need for Threads.  It instead uses an OS-level IO feature that the JVM taps into.  Using my model, if I allocated N threads for IO and N threads were doing long-term IO, then future small requests added to the queue would have to wait until those slow connections (which may be slow due to a malicious client) finished.  Do I have the gist of it?

Comment: Yes, I had a similar problem before when sharing a big ThreadPool with slow and fast tasks.  The fast tasks would eventually become just as slow because all the slow tasks would be hogging the pool.  The same can happen with your solution.  Now of course, this may be pretty far fetched for your use case, and your infra may already have protections in place to prevent such attacks.

Comment: Hah!  I was thinking of that being a potential solution!  Of course, at that point it would probably be easier to use NIO.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a web server with some N number of threads using the model you've described a malicious actor could open N connections and simply send no data. Now your server is completely locked up and unable to do meaningful work. What NIO brings to the table are selectors which allow you to wait on ***multiple*** connections at once. With this primitive you can create a thread to wait on ***all*** the current connections. No one connection can take up the execution status of an entire thread because you've only given that job to a single thread. All the other threads on your system can now handle the incoming data as needed.

Even assuming normal, non-malicious actors the one-thread/blocking-call model can break down. You're correct that IO operations can get stuck and it could cause a failure in your system. However certain clients (say persistent clients in a chat session) may idle for long periods of time. All requests to servers are not necessarily immediate and complete.

Comment: Any non-trivial server will defend against such an attack via read timeouts.

Comment: Sure, you could set SO_TIMEOUT. But you can't use that as a mechanism to discard connections because fragmentation exists. With some extremely small read timeout, let's say 5ms, someone could trickle 1 byte at a time of a 1k byte request. You've cumulatively wasted 5 seconds of real server time on just one connection. Even without malicious users you're incurring the overhead of a context switch and a potential exception (because that's how java manifests the timeout) per read from the socket.